# Multiple Webpack entry points: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chatroom is not defined"

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using multiple entry points with webpack however my object constructors don't seem to have global scope even after being declared in my html file.

For example:

- in my first bundle, I have a object constructor called 'Chatroom'
- I make reference to this in my secon bundle however in the console I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chatroom is not defined".

I've double checked the bundles are declared in the correct order in my html file but still have this problem

My webpack config looks like:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
     mode: 'development',
     entry: {
        app: './src/app/app.js',
        chat: './src/chat/chat.js',
        ui: './src/ui/ui.js'
    },
     output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true
};

module.exports = config;
```

I create a new chatroom object in chat.js

```
class Chatroom {
  constructor (room, username){
    this.room = room;
    this.username = username;
    this.chats = colRef
    this.unsub;
  }
```

I order my bundles in the html like this:

```
    <script src="chat.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="ui.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
```

then when I try to create a class instance in app.js like this:

```
const chatroom = new Chatroom('general', 'dan');
```

I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chatroom is not defined"

Since chat.bundle.js comes before app.bundle.js I would expect app.bundle.js to have access to the constructor

Comment: Bundles don't load each other, they are fully self-contained files with any dependencies already bundled into those files. So you're telling webpack to make three _separate_ bundles, each set to run starting in the files you indicate as entry point, and any code they rely on they should already be importing/requiring, so if your `App.js` tries to make a `new Chatroom`, it needs to have an explicit import/require for `Chatroom`, and webpack is going to add that import/require into the bundle. So a core question here is: _why_ are you making three bundles? Why did you think you had to do that?

Comment: Ah thank you, I am still learning and haven't looked at importing properly yet. I am making bundles to use Firebase 9 in my project. I am also following a tutorial (however the tutorial uses an older version of firebase so it is not modular) where he creates 3 separate js files.

Comment: While inconvenient, it might be worth finding a more recent tutorial, because webpack's change a lot over the years as well.